# Sap UI5 editing object template

Tags: sapui5

I want to add two buttons inside the combobox object. Is that possible to edit object's template ? What should I do ?
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You could extend the ComboBox or the Input. Have a look at the Developer Guide on extending Controls and post your code.

Answer (score 1):

Those two buttons are somewhat mutual exclusive because they both pull up a value help, but in a different way. From a UX perspective I would try to stay away from solutions like these and make the user's life better by picking the one that is most appropriate in that specific scenario. E.g. Pull down combo in case there are e.g. 15 entries. But offer more advanced value help if the number of entries to pick from exceeds 50. Note that this is just a rough suggestion, not a rule of thumb or something, and depends on the user-scenario.

If you still want to go ahead, you'll have to create a custom control that combines features of e.g. `sap.m.select` control (drop down) with valuehelp features of the `sap.m.input` control. Step 34 of the UI5 walk-though may help you to get started: https://openui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/d12d2ee6a5454d799358d425f9e7c4db.html